# Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sass": java.io.IOException

Tags: ant, jenkins, automation, sass

I am trying to do Sass compilation via Jenkins job but I am getting below error.

- I am Linux machine for compilation.
- Gem installation
- But when I say sass -v nothing is showing and when I hit `gem list | grep -i sass` I can see the version.

How can the fix the issue

**Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sass": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory**

```
<target name="build-sass-to-css">
        <echo message="Compiling scss files to css..." />
        <!-- create the css destination dir if it doesn't already exist -->
        <mkdir dir="${destCssDir}/responsive"/>
        <mkdir dir="${destNonMinCssDir}"/>
        <echo message="Running sass executable against sass files and compiling to CSS directory [${destCssDir}/responsive] " />
        <!-- run sass executable -->
        <parallel threadCount="2">
            <apply executable="sass" dest="${destCssDir}/responsive" verbose="true" force="true" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="--style"/>
                <arg value="compressed"/>
                <arg value="--sourcemap=none"/>
                <srcfile />
                <targetfile />
                <fileset dir="${srcSassDir}" includes="**/*.scss,**/*.sass" excludes="**/_*"/>
                <mapper type="glob" from="*.scss" to="*.css"/>
            </apply>
            <apply executable="sass" dest="${destNonMinCssDir}" verbose="true" force="true" failonerror="true">
                <srcfile />
                <targetfile />
                <fileset dir="${srcSassDir}" includes="**/*.scss,**/*.sass"  excludes="**/_*"/>
                <mapper type="glob" from="*.scss" to="*.css"/>
            </apply>
```

Comment: If you type `sass` into your console and hit tab to autocomplete the command, what happens?  On my dev system, all ruby related commands have a suffix of `19` (eg. `sass19`, `gem19`, etc.).  Alternately, you may need to reset your terminal.

Comment: In Solaris when I hit sass+tab I can see sass and sass-convert but in Linux I dont see any response ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much more than this, but it sounds like the path to your gems isn't in your PATH, if that makes sense?